# Android menu item fade out when touched

Tags: android

I am pretty sure there's a trivial answer for this but I can't find it anywhere (perhaps I am using the wrong term?)

I am trying to make the menu item background slightly darker when the finger is pressed down on it (like in Gmail app). How can I achieve this effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

do you mean, pressing a list, change its background color when it's pressed?
if that's what you mean, you can use [selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html),
see [here](http://www.michenux.net/android-listview-highlight-selected-item-387.html) for some example

Comment: Talking about menu items in actionbar. Not listview.

Answer (score -2):

Just create a new layout for menu item pressed and implement it. :D